# Why I cannot await object type?

Tags: c#, async-await

Recently I realized that I can make actually anything awaitable if I implement a `GetAwaiter` extension method for the type. I know it is completely nonsense but I started to play with that just for fun:

```
// a minimal awaiter to make the compiler happy
public class MyAwaiter<T> : INotifyCompletion
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; } = true

    public T GetResult() => default(T);

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) { }
}
```

And the required extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // await them all!
    public static MyAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return new MyAwaiter<T>();
    }
}
```

Now I can commit this black magic:

```
private async Task Magic()
{
    await "haha!";
    await 42;
    // await new object(); // <- this line does not compile
}
```

Awaiting an object fails:

> `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<object>` does not contain a definition for `IsCompleted`

I do not understand how `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<object>` comes in when I return a `MyAwaiter<T>` instance. But never mind, second try:

```
public static MyAwaiter<object> GetAwaiter(this object obj)
{
    return new MyAwaiter<object>();
}
```

Now none of the awaits work:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `Test.Extensions.GetAwaiter(object)` and `Test.Extensions.GetAwaiter(object)`

This is even more confusing message than the previous one.

If I change the type in the signature to `string` or `int`, then I can await strings and integers respectively; however, `object` does not work. Has someone any clue what in the background happens in case of `object`?

Comment: If you keep both `MyAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>(T)` and `MyAwaiter<object> GetAwaiter(object)`, how is the compiler going to pick one over the other? C# doesn't have template specialization like C#. If you try to call `GetAwaiter(new object())`, *both* extension methods are equally suitable - or rather, the generic one creates a concrete method just as suitable as the other one

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I do not have two extension methods at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem I can see is a missing semicolon：

```
public bool IsCompleted { get; } = true
```

Your code before your second try (the first 3 pieces of code) including `await new object();` compiles on my machine, just like expected. I tried both .NET CORE and .NET framework 4.6 console applications in VS 2017 Community v15.2(26430.6).

Check your code and compiler version again.

Comment: The semicolon was a typo of course. But you were right, I changed the target framework to 4.6 and it is working now. I do not know how I missed it. :)